# Are there performance issues of being a client of your own API?

Tags: performance, web-services, api, rest

Take Twitter for example, they say twitter.com as a client of their own API. Could this be one of the reason why Twitter is quite 'slow'?

Reference: http://engineering.twitter.com/2010/09/tech-behind-new-twittercom.html

Would you recommend using your own API for you main website/app?

If using own API is OK, what are the ways to avoid performance issues?

Comment: Stack Overflow uses its own API too. Do you consider it slow?

Comment: If you provide a Client(a client may even be a WebApplication) your client is allways the user of your own API. How your client communicates with the Servers depends on your requirements. If there exists a public API there exists nearby no reason why your client should not use this API.

Comment: @Mat - Not really but won't it be any faster if it didn't?

Comment: @IMB: why would it be? Your question isn't answerable. It depends on the design & use of the specific API. A badly designed API won't work well. Using a properly designed API correctly will work. There's no magic.

Comment: Apparently there's a smilar question which says there's some performance issues stackoverflow.com/questions/3590561/is-it-good-practice-for-a-website-to-use-its-own-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regarding using your own API:** It's about trade offs. In the twitter example by using their own API they were able to "allocate more resources to the API team." That benefit for them outweighed a performance hit. There are other benefits not mentioned either, Like, being the first to vet your api and having a single unified entry point into the system.  There are drawbacks as well that are mentioned in the link you posted.

For your application you should look at the architectural qualities you want to achieve and balance that with the constraints you are given and make your own choice. If ultra high performance is at the top of the list then craft your solution to meet that goal.

**Regarding performance when using your own API:** Again it depends. In the twitter case they knew they would be accessing the API in JavaScript. So the physical jumps are Browser --> Server --> DB.  There is no way to get around these hops if you are doing client-server development.  In the link you posted they talked about going directly to the DB. Yes that would be faster, but I'm not sure how to do that from a javascript client.  I suppose if they had used websockets to a custom API then that would have been faster, but at what development cost.

**Summary** So it's not that they are using their own API that was the performance hit, it was that they wanted the client to be an HTTP hop away. 
Please note that none of these comments talk about what the server --> db calls look like or their caching strategy, or any of the other dozen things which could be a bottleneck